# How do I close the lightbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, lightbox

I've made a code which shows a lightbox when you enter the page. Like a popup window. It should in theory close when you press on 'x' which appears in the corner of the box but for some reason the code doesn't work properly and it fails to close so that the lightbox stays there. Does anyone have any suggestions? Help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
lightBoxClose = function() {
  document.querySelector(".lightbox").classList.add("closed");
  }
```

```css
.lightbox {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.toolbarLB {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 3px;
}
.closeLB {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.lightbox .iframeContainer {
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #CCC;
  padding: 2px;
 background:rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}
.lightbox.closed {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="lightbox">
  <div class="iframeContainer">
    <div class="toolbarLB">
      <span class="closeLB" onclick="lightBoxClose()">x</span>
    </div>
    
    <p align="center">More text is here</p>
    
    <h1>Just text</h1>
    </div>
    
  </div>
```

Comment: I updated your code snippet and it works. If what you had originally was on your site, it's because you had the JS inside of your `<style>` tags.

Comment: No plugin, you need to put the JS inside `<script>` tags, not in `<style>` tags.

Answer (score -1):

In your snippet its already working so just make sure you put your javascript within `<script>` tags and the `<script>` within the `<body>`tags.